# Firebase onDataChange returns null value after internet reconnection

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code to read data and write the value into an object

```
if(SpecialFunction.isNetworkAvailable()) {
    databaseContent.loadAccountFromDatabase(account -> {
        this.account = account;
        binding.textView3.setText(account.toString());
    });
} else {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, InternetTroubleActivity.class));
}
```

Where databaseContent is a class which contains Firebase logic which I need.
In loadAccountFromDatabase I have next code which works with one problem.

```
  public void loadAccountFromDatabase(FirebaseCallbackAccount accountFirebaseCallback) {
     ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                account = snapshot.getValue(Account.class);
            } else {
                account = new Account();
                setDefaultAccount();
            }
            accountFirebaseCallback.onCallback(account);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Log.e("loadAccountFromDatabase", "Error:  " + error.toString());
        }
    };
    database.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
}
```

When I try to read data after internet reconnection or when I turn on internet after onStart() and run loadAccountFromDatabase I get null value of my snapshot.
I have a method (isNetworkAvailable()) which works well and when I don't have internet connection it returns false.
The next part of code doesn't work properly. The snapshot.exists returns true and snapshot.getValue returns null although the value is other.

```
if (snapshot.exists()) {
    account = snapshot.getValue(Account.class);
}
```

If I run an application with internet connection everything works well while I don't turn off internet and try to read again.
I also tried to use database.get().addOnCompleteListener(onCompleteListener)... but I got the same result. Everything works well while I don't try to read data after internet reconnection.

`database.keepSynced(true)` also doesn't help.

### UPDATE##

Database init:

```
private final String USER_KEY = "Account", PURCHASES = "purchases";

    public void init() {
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        database = firebaseDatabase.getReference(String.format("%s/%s", USER_KEY, mAuth.getUid()));
    }
```

Structure:
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9Bsa.png)

### UPDATE 2##

To help you understand the problem I add screenshot of log. GREEN box: I run my app with internet connection. The data was read and wrote correct. RED box: I closed my app, destroyed activity, turned off internet. Then I run my app, but method isNetworkAvailable didn't let me run MainActivity. Then I turned on internet and clicked on button. The data was being tried to read but I got object with null variables althrough they are not null. If you think that something is wrong with isNetworkAvailable I tell you that this problem was before I have added it. I was hoping that it would help me to read correct but it didn't help.
[logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AayAS.png)

### UPDATE 3##

JSON:

```
{
  "Account" : {
    "wBOZsnGGywYIpap3cLZodPOWcpt2" : {
      "budget" : 100,
      "budgetLastMonth" : 0,
      "budgetLeft" : 100,
      "currencyType" : "USD",
      "email" : "bibishka117@gmail.com",
      "id" : "wBOZsnGGywYIpap3cLZodPOWcpt2",
      "personName" : "новый пользователь"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How is the variable `database` initialized?

Comment: how many seconds between internet reconnected and you trying to access it, sometimes the "link" is online but no actual traffic comming

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez I am trying to read data just after connection is restored. When onDataChange was run the data in console also changes to null value.

Comment: Can you log the value of `mAuth.getUid()` in your code, and show us the updated code and its log output? Then can you also show the JSON (as text, no screenshots please) that you think should be read for that UID? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added mAuth.getUid() inside onDataChange and I get correct uid each time when I use onDataChange. I don't think that log output helps you to understand something because uid is the same before/after connecting to the internet. Check my update 2.

Answer (score 1):

I found a problem. 4 hours of reading my code and stackoverflow. I don't know how, but in onPause () I had code that writes null object to a database.
So when I tested and turned on / off the Internet, I run it. So I wrote a null object that was not instantly updated on the console, and when I turned on the Internet, the object was updated to zero in the database and then read in my app. :]